# Is there a way to use T1 font for math and main font (with some T2A Cyrillic letters) in document compiled by XeLaTeX?

Tags: fontspec, font-encodings, cyrillic

Here is my code (utf8):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{anttor}
\begin{document}
text $math$

Russian: Щ
\end{document}
```

The problem is, "math" is still the CM font; and the Cyrillic font does not appear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Antykwa Toruńska font has support for the Cyrillic script and also for math; if you want to use XeLaTeX, then this is how you can do it

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math]{anttor}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Antykwa Torunska}

\begin{document}
text $math$

Russian: Щ
\end{document}
```

You may need to find out how to actually load the AT font on your machine, possibly with

```
\setmainfont[
  Ligatures = TeX,
  Extension = .otf,
  UprightFont = *-Regular,
  BoldFont = *-Bold,
  ItalicFont = *-Italic,
  BoldItalicFont = *-Italic
]{AntykwaTorunska}
```

that should work with a TeX Live distribution. If you have installed the Antykwa Toruńska fonts in your system, then the simpler declaration above should suffice.

[image]

If you want to use `pdflatex`, then the approach with font encodings is necessary:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[math]{anttor}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\cyr}[1]{%
  {\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont#1}%
}

\begin{document}
text $math$

Russian: \cyr{Щ}
\end{document}
```

It's not possible to write Cyrillic characters without changing the font encoding, unfortunately, without extensive work.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to use `inputenc` and `fontenc` packages with XeLaTeX, since it already works with Unicode. So you have first to remove the lines:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
```

Then you have to use fonts which contain Unicode glyphs. The corresponding of Computer Modern (CM) are Computer Modern Unicode (CMU).

If you change your MWE to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}
\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}

\begin{document}
text $math$

Russian: Щ
\end{document}
```

and compile it with XeLaTeX, it should work.

Comment: And what about `anttor`? You're overriding it, which is not wanted.

Comment: @egreg You are right, I forgot to delete that line. Anyway there is your answer now, to explain how to use `anttor` with XeLaTeX. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, using `inputenc` with XeTeX is wrong. XeTeX treats `Щ` as one Unicode character (U+0429), while pdfTeX treats it as two characters (0xD0, 0xA9) in UTF-8 encoding. That's a big difference.

If you want to typeset Cyrillic letters in XeTeX, it is better to use a Unicode font (TrueType or OpenType) with [`fontspec`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/fontspec) package, as karlkoeller said. Not all fonts supports Cyrillic letters. For CM fonts, CMU families are good choices.

---

It is still possible, however, to use the old `T2A` fonts.

```
\XeTeXinputencoding "byte"
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{anttor}
\begin{document}
text $math$

Russian: Щ
\end{document}
```

But in this case, `fontspec` is not used at all, and why not use pdfTeX directly?

Answer (score 2):

If you just need cyriliic letters in math, try `\text{}` command from `amsmath` package. It works with any engine, either (pdf)latex or xelatex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\ifxetex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{CMU Serif}
  \setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}
  \setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}
\else
  \usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\fi
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}% you need babel 3.9

\begin{document}
\[
\text{Щ}
\]
Russian: Щ
\end{document}
```